# Get all images in a specific category in wikimedia

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikimedia-commons

I am looking for an efficient way to get the all images in a specific category in wikimedia commons.

```
Example : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Quality_images
```

The following image is in the category  above:
`https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg`

How can i get the links of all the images in that category ?

Ultimately i will use the image urls to query the api to get direct links for the original images.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json
```

The images will be used in an ML dataset

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13395/16193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Commons:Quality images` is not a [category](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories), it's a page in the [project namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces#Project).

If you want all the images contained in that page you can use the [`images` API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images):

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&titles=Commons:Quality%20images&imlimit=500&format=json&utf8

Answer (score 0):

One API query response has a limit of 500. To ensure your code's resilience and handling of larger categories you need to recursively query the API using `continue.cmcontinue` if you query using [`list=categorymembers`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtype=file&cmtitle=Category:Videos_Langue_des_signes_fran%C3%A7aise&cmlimit=500&format=json&origin=*). Append `&origin=*` or it could fail due to xhr cross origin.

I wrote a code to go recursive within a large category, and on multiple target categories : https://jsfiddle.net/dekz6Lbu/5/ using JS promises. If you remove GPT's and my comments it's not that long.

See also : https://mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Continue